# Spring restTemplate timeout without throwing exceptioin

Tags: spring, rest, httpclient, resttemplate

I found a timeout issue on my backend service: SA.
SA send request to 3party api with restTemplate:

```
try {
   log.info("sending request to sb"); //position 1
   return restTemplate.postForObject("https://url.to.sb.com", null, String.class);
}catch(Exception ex) {
   log.error("request error", ex) //position 2
}
```

The sb service is working normally.
Browser get gateway timeout error .
Logs on position 1 is printed but position 2 is not printed.

Here is how I compose the restTemplate:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
httpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(xxxx);
CloseableHttpClient client = httpClientBuilder.build();
restTemplate.setInterceptors(Arrays.asList(new DefaultHttpRequestInterceptor()));
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new 
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory));
return restTemplate;
```

Why frontend get gateway timeout, but there isn't error log on SA ?
Seems that thread is pending. And this issue is resolved after restart SA .
But I still want to know the possible causes of this issue,
not sure it's related with requestFactory setTimeout

Comment: Why should it, you don't set a connection timeout so it will wait indefinitly.

Comment: @M.Deinum, the 3party api sb is working and I've tested it with cURL command, it's very fast.  why connection timeout  is only happen when use resttemplate?

Comment: Proxies, routes, could be a combination of things. Also the timeout you get is on the client side (hence the request handling) not on the server side because you haven't set a connection timeout/read timeout. And also are you sure that it hangs on the `postForObject` or some other path in the controller/endpoint that is handling the request.

Comment: I'm sure it was hangs on 'postForObject' since no logs from catch block is printed

Comment: That could also mean that there is no exception and something else is blocking.